# Seriously though, how is this a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, duplicates

[This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/234281/these-it-much-many-macaroni), which asked:

> You've got macaroni spilt all over your house. Which one would be a correct version?
>
> 1. These are too much macaroni.
> 2. These are too many macaroni.
> 3. It's too much macaroni.

was closed as a duplicate of [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/60905/how-do-i-pluralize-italian-foods-like-pasta-noodles-spaghetti-macaroni), which asked:

> Is it proper to say *spaghettis* for more than one spaghetti noodle?  What about *macaronis* as a plural for more than one macaroni noodle?

How is a question that accepts *macaroni* as singular/noncountable and asks only about which modifier to use with it a duplicate of a question that explicitly asks whether *macaroni* should be treated as countable in the first place and says nothing about modifiers? Is it because they both mention macaroni? Are all questions involving macaroni henceforth to be treated as duplicates of what is apparently now the macaroni ur-question? If so, shouldn't we consider creating a [macaroni](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macaroni) tag to help us properly administer and process these things?

Comment: The answer (to both questions) comes from the fact spaghetti/macaroni are both mass nouns and so are singular. So both are equally closable and ell-able.

Comment: Because both questions are *How do I pluralize *macaroni*?"?

Comment: @Mitch Yes, so that means this question was wrongly closed as it wasn't closed as ELL, it was closed as a dupe.

Comment: @Araucaria It was closed correctly as a duplicate. Also ell-able but that is not a current close reason in the system.

Answer (score 5):

The two questions deal with how to pluralize macaroni. Both questions are badly worded but I disagree that one question is just "do we use an s or not". Either way, the proper answer to both questions is the same: macaroni is usually used as a mass noun. Mass nouns take singular agreement. The older question asks about pluralizing the mass noun with an s, the newer seems to waver about whether or not it is a mass noun or what the plural form might be, but they boil down to the same thing.

A bigger problem, IMO, is that [the older question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/60905/how-do-i-pluralize-italian-foods-like-pasta-noodles-spaghetti-macaroni) is closed as a duplicate of other questions that do not really duplicate it, so we cannot provide a better answer to both questions there.